# Visual feedback for restricting drag and drop in a list

Tags: error-message, drag-n-drop, error-prevention

I have a table with a list of items. Users are able to drag and drop each item up and down to reorder the items.

I want to set some control in place. For example, in the table below, I want to disable the user from dragging the item 'lime' before 'apple'.

I'm looking for visual examples of immediate feedback that indicates that you're not allowed to drag an item to somewhere, thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When the user selects an item to drag, change the color of all valid positions to bright green, and invalid to dark red.

[image]

Additionally when the item is on top of an invalid position, you may display the following symbol :

[image]

And when on top of a valid position display the symbol :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Create space for the element where user can drop:

[image]

## Use red border with blocked icon where user can't drop

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas:

- When the user is dragging the *lime* and is going to pass over the *apple*, the *lime* pushes the *apple* on its way.
  The same would happen the other way round (when the *apple* goes down).
- Display all the possible locations of the item when the user starts dragging the item (in the image example it would be the *lime*):

[image: Second idea]